# When the input is bigger than 9999, I need the output to be "entered number is invalid"

Tags: c

I have a problem with my output when the input is bigger than 9999. I need the out to be "entered number is invalid".

```
#include <stdio.h> 

main() 
{   
    int num;

    printf("Enter a number: ");
    scanf("%d", &num);      
{
    

    if(num<0 || num>9999)
    {  printf("entered number is not valid\n");}
    
    
    //four digits
    if (num >= 9000)       
    {
    printf("nine thousand ");
    num -= 9000;}
    
    else if (num >= 8000)       
    {
    printf("eight thousand ");
    num -= 8000;}
    
    else if (num >= 7000)       
    {
    printf("seven thousand ");
    num -= 7000;}
    
    else if (num >= 6000)       
    {
    printf("six thousand ");
    num -= 6000;}
    
    else if (num >= 5000)       
    {
    printf("five thousand ");
    num -= 5000;}
    
    else if (num >= 4000)       
    {
    printf("four thousand ");
    num -= 4000;}
    
    else if (num >= 3000)       
    {
    printf("three thousand ");
    num -= 3000;}
    
    else if (num >= 2000)       
    {
    printf("two thousand ");
    num -= 2000;}
    
    
    else if (num >= 1000)       
    {
    printf("one thousand ");
    num -= 1000;}
     
     //three digits
    if (num >= 900)   
    { printf("nine hundred ");
    num -= 900; }
    
    if (num >= 800)   
    { printf("eight hundred ");
    num -= 800;}
    
    if (num >= 700)   
    { printf("seven hundred ");
    num -= 700;}
    
    if (num >= 600)   
    { printf("six hundred ");
    num -= 600;}
    
    if (num >= 500)   
    { printf("five hundred ");
    num -= 500;}
    
     if (num >= 400)   
    { printf("four hundred ");
    num -= 400;}
     
     if (num >= 300)   
    { printf("three hundred ");
    num -= 300;}
    
     if (num >= 200)   
    { printf("twohundred ");
    num -= 200;}
     
    if (num >= 100)   
    { printf("one hundred ");
    num -= 100;}
    
    //two digits
    
    if (num >= 90)   
    { printf("ninety ");
    num -= 90;}
    
    
    if (num >= 80)
    { printf("eighty ");
    num -= 80;}
    
    if (num >= 70)
    { printf("seventy ");
    num -= 70;}
    
    if (num >= 60)
    { printf("sixty ");
    num -= 60;}
    
    if (num >= 50)
    { printf("fifty ");
    num -= 50;}
    
    if (num >= 40)
    { printf("fourty ");
    num -= 40;}
    
    if (num >= 30)
    { printf("thirty ");
    num -= 30;}
    
    if (num >= 20)
    { printf("twenty ");
    num -= 20;}
    
//10-19 numbers
    if (num >= 19)
    { printf("nineteen ");
    num -= 19;}
    
    if (num >= 18)
    { printf("eighteen ");
    num -= 18;}
    
    if (num >= 17)
    { printf("seventeen ");
    num -= 17;}

    if (num >=16 )
    { printf("sixteen ");
    num -= 16;}
    
    if (num >=15 )
    { printf("fifteen ");
    num -= 15;}
    
    if (num >=14 )
    { printf("fourteen ");
    num -= 14;}
    
    if (num >=13 )
    { printf("thirteen ");
    num -= 13;}
    
    if (num >=12 )
    { printf("twelve ");
    num -= 12;}
    
    if (num >=11 )
    { printf("eleven ");
    num -= 11;}
    
    if (num >=10 )
    { printf("ten ");
    num -= 10;}
// one digit
    if (num >=9 )
    { printf("nine ");
    num -= 9 ;}
    
    if (num >= 8)   
    {
    printf("eight ");
    num -= 8;}
    
    if (num >= 7)
    { printf("seven ");
    num -= 7;}
    
    if (num >=6 )
    { printf("six ");
    num -= 6;}
    
    if (num >= 5)
    { printf("five ");
    num -= 5;}
    
    if (num >=4 )
    { printf("four");
    num -= 4;}
    
    if (num >= 3)
    { printf("three ");
    num -= 3;}
    
    if (num >=2 )
    { printf("two ");
    num -= 2;}
    
    if (num >= 1)
    { printf("one ");
    num -=1 ;}
    
    
 
}
}
```

//Input: 99999

Output: entered number is not valid
nine thousand nine hundred eight hundred seven hundred six hundred five hundred four hundred three hundred twohundred one hundred ninety eighty seventy sixty fifty fourty thirty twenty nineteen eighteen seventeen sixteen fifteen fourteen thirteen twelve eleven ten nine eight seven six five fourthree two one

Target output: entered number is not valid

Comment: Please describe both what you expect/want to happen, and what actually is happening. We need to understand what you want before we can help you get there

Comment: After you print the error message, your code continues.  Instead, you need to add a call to `exit` (or, since this is `main`, you could instead `return`) after printing the error message.

Comment: You need to avoid any printing of the number after the test for when the input is invalid — use an `else { … }` block to surround all the number printing material.  Your code layout is hard to read.  You should probably be using a table-driven approach to avoid so much replication.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I will try your advice. Still had trouble understanding it since I only started 5 days ago. Only have youtube and my friend's school activities to learn programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Use the correct main definition.
2. Always check the `scanf` return value
3. You need to skip printing if `scanf` was not cusscessfull or number is < 0 or > 9999.

```
int main(void) 
{   
    int num;

    printf("Enter a number: ");
    if(scanf("%d", &num) != 1 || num<0 || num>9999)
    {
        printf("entered number is not valid\n"); 
        return 1;
    }
    /* .... */
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried it and it worked. As a beginner, this really helped me. I would try solving this in a more efficient way while using your advice.